# MouseDown on WPF - Using ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, mousedown

I have trying to show list of company, each company has some information like logo, name and ...

I want to show company page when user touch any part of list, here is what I provide:

```
 <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollCompany"    >
  <StackPanel Name="stCompany" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>


for(int i=0;i<maxCompany;i++)
{
     Grid objMain = new Grid();
      objMain.Name = "companyId" +  companyId;
    objMain.MouseDown += objCompany_MouseDown;

    // here I have adding logo and name and other thing ...

    stCompany.Children.Add(objMain);
}
```

Now when I try to touch logo or label, MouseDown works, but I couldn't touch grid or parent of labels,logo

Even I have using WrapPanel,StackPanel instead of Grid

Comment: Forgive me if this is incorrect, as my WPF experience is far from that in UWP. But could you not use a stackpanel, house your data inside of that stackpanel using labels etc, and then set the stackpanels.tapped event handler (click or similar) to complete what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: because your grid needs a transparent background !!

Comment: @jj- thanks for your suggest, but I have using stackpanel because I not going to set marging for each item, may you didn't get how stackpanel works

Comment: this one ==> Grid objMain = new Grid(); ==> stackpanel is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the grid needs a transparent background. Otherwise (if Background is null) WPF will not consider the control in hit testing:

```
objMain.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```